# Spring security AuthenticationServiceException converted to InsufficientAuthenticationException

Tags: spring, exception, spring-security

I've a problem with exception handling during authentication using Spring Security.

This is my `AuthenticationProvider` where on every exception an `AuthenticationServiceException` is thrown.

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            // ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Below my custom `AuthenticationProvider`.

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.debug(e.toString());
    }
}
```

This is the security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }
}
```

Everything is triggered as expected. The problem is that in the `AuthenticationProvider` the `AuthenticationException` is an instance of `InsufficientAuthenticationException` and not `AuthenticationServiceException` as thrown by the `AuthenticationProvider`.
What I want instead in `MyAuthenticationEntryPoint` is the exception thrown with the cause set, which is a custom exception.

How can I solve this? 
Why Spring replace an `AuthenticationServiceException` with an `InsufficientAuthenticationException`?

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution! The problem is in `SecurityConfig` class. `.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)` must be under `.httpBasic()` and not set globally.

The right configuration is the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Just a sanity check: There is also `AuthorizationServiceException` - the spelling is close, so can you confirm that you are indeed throwing an `AuthenticationServiceException` (the compiler wouldn't catch the mismatch since both are runtime exceptions)

Comment: You mean in MyAuthenticationEntryPoint the AuthenticationException is an instance of InsufficientAuthenticationException. Change it, it is confusing. And btw I have the same issue if it is an issue. Only thing I can think of is trying to follow the flow by debugging and see where Spring does the conversion and if there is a setting to turn it off. I know that Spring does this sometimea because I have followed the thrown of the 'usernamenotfoundexception' and this also gets converted each time to 'badcredentialsexception'. If you find a solution post it. Thx

Comment: @jzheaux as showed above the used exception is AuthenticationServiceException. I've also tried with BadCredentialsException that is another implementation of org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException.

Comment: @Merv I followed the flow and the problem is that when AccessDecisionManager is involved used is not authenticated, hence is access is denied. In my case AffirmativeBased implementation is used

Comment: Se above in the question for the solution

Comment: thanks for pointing in the right way this solution is only for usage of the httpbasic filter and not other filters.